# Moving several objects in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Let's suppose I have a NSMutableArray like this:

Object 0
Object 1
Object 2
Object 3
Object 4

and would like to take Object 0 and Object 1 and move them behind Object 4:

Object 2
Object 3
Object 4
Object 0
Object 1

I have this rather long code to achieve the re-ordering of multiple objects, but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward / elegant way:

```
    int from = 0;
    int to = 5;
    int lastIndexOfObjectsToBeMoved = 1;    
    NSMutableArray *objectsToBeMoved = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = from; i < lastIndexOfObjectsToBeMoved; i++) {
        object *o = [self.objects objectAtIndex:i];
        [objectsToBeMoved addObject:o];
    }

    NSUInteger length = lastIndexOfObjectsToBeMoved-from;
    NSRange indicesToBeDeleted = NSMakeRange(from, length);
    [self.objects removeObjectsInRange:indicesToBeDeleted];


    NSIndexSet *targetIndices = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(to, length)];
    [self.objects insertObjects:objectsToBeMoved atIndexes:targetIndices];
```

---

Edit: sorry, I should have clarified, I'm not always moving objects to the very end, but would also like to be able to do things like moving object 2 and 3 to index 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an NSRange of the indexes you want to move to the back. Grab those objects with `subarrayWithRange`, remove them with `removeObjectsInRange:` and add them back to the end by calling `addObjectsFromArray:`. This is a much more concise way of writing what you have.

Comment: problem is that I'm not always moving stuff to the very end. Let's suppose I wanted to move objects 3-4 to index 1. So I can't simply use addObjectsFromArray. But I guess I could do that with subarrayWithRang as well...

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use `subarrayWithRange:`, `removeObjectsInRange:`, with the same range (thus, eliminating the for loop in the original method), and then `insertObjects:atIndexes:` with the target locations.

Comment: In most situations, you end up moving one object at a time, where using a category method such as the one described [here](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/) makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

rowIndexes is a NSIndexSet with objects you like move

row is the index destination

```
NSArray *objectsToMove = [your_array objectsAtIndexes: rowIndexes];

// If any of the removed objects come before the row
// we want to decrement the row appropriately
row -= [rowIndexes countOfIndexesInRange: (NSRange){0, row}];

[your_array removeObjectsAtIndexes:rowIndexes];
[your_array replaceObjectsInRange: (NSRange){row, 0}
       withObjectsFromArray: objectsToMove];
```

I hope this helps you